# execute a python code on Azure VM using Synapse

Tags: automation, azure-logic-apps, azure-automation, azure-synapse

I need suggestions on how to create a pipeline in Azure Synapse that performs/automates the following steps once a week:

1. Access/connect with an Azure Virtual Machine
2. Find and run a code in python

The general objective is: for each new file saved in blob storage, the pipeline starts to run, access the VM and execute the code.

I'm a little confused if I should use Logic Apps or Azure Automation.
Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I think this would be a slightly unusual pattern  Why not just convert the Python code to run in a Synapse Notebook?  Then it can be easily scheduled from a Synapse Pipeline using the Notebook activity.  You can even parameterise the notebook, and hook into blob triggers so it would respond to your "file landing" event.  I can do a more detailed answer with some links if required?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create a Python script directly in the Synapse Notebook and access the files in the blob storage. You can also trigger the Notebook using Synapse pipeline based on any event in the blob storage. Check [Create, develop, and maintain Synapse notebooks in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks).

And synapse is good when you work with SQL Pool. If you only want to work with files in blob, go for Azure data factory which give fives you better options, like trigger the pipeline based on event in blob storage. You can run python script using [custom activity in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory).

And, you can run the event based trigger in ADF for any event in blob storage. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory

Comment: Thank you UtkarshPal-MT. Actually, we are working with pyspark notebooks runnning in Az  Synapse. My questions is: I have a VM that upload data and from Synapse (using an activity - may call Az Automation) access this VM and the sorage where the data is saved.
Resume: i need create a pipeline in Synapse to access VM and start this code that upload the data.
Thanks Monica.

Comment: It worked for you?